# Is there any way to undo a move?

Tags: warhammer-total-war

When I say move, I mean like I move an army from point A to point B. Sometimes I clicked on the wrong area, or forgot to change move type. Is there any way to undo it so I can remove the character in that turn?

Comment: I wonder this too, only way I have found is to reload to the save from before.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do this :/ but as Lyrion said you can use the last autosave to go back a turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to undo a move and I will explain why:
If there was a "undo" button, you can just free explore, move full to one direction, see what is in there and then just undo a do it on another direction. That would be cheating and I think there is no undo thing on any Total War, despite of the firts Total War Vikings game that you move army like chess pieces on a 2D map.

I recommend to left click and drag on the map to see the yellow line and think where are you gonna move and see on the left movement bar, what amount ot movement will you gonna expend to do that. It helps a lot.

Comment: "you can just free explore" this is not true if they were to limit the "undo" action to movements that do not reveal any new map.  This mechanic exists on, for example, Battle for Wesnoth.  If you move a character, and no map area was revealed that wasn't already visible due to other characters/towns/whatever, then you can undo, else, you cannot undo.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any specific undo option or button, if you really need to go back some steps the only way to do that as far as I know is to load a save file.

Comment: This doesn't add anything new to the existing answer of 7sega7.